# how to convert arguments into flat array

Tags: javascript, arguments

consider this piece of code:

```
 function test() {
   console.log(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments));
 }

 test([1,2]); // returns [ Array[2] ];
```

I want to get a flat array [1,2] and not [ Array[2] ].
Also I don't want to call test.apply(null, [1,2]), I need to pass-in a proper array [1,2] as arguments.

Comment: console.log(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments)[0]); ? But why do you want to return what you're sending?

Comment: Why do you want to use `arguments` at all? Just log the one parameter that you're given. Or use `console.log.apply(console, arguments)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Slice only the first argument?

```
function test() {
    console.log(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments[0]));
}

test([1,2]);
```

Or loop through the arguments flattening the array:

```
function test() {
    var args = [],
        i = 0;
    for ( ; i < arguments.length; ++i )
    {
        if ( Array.isArray( arguments[i] ) )
            Array.prototype.push.apply( args, arguments[i] );
        else
            args.push( arguments[i] );
    }
    console.log( args );
}

test([1,2], [3,4,5], 6, [7], 8, 9);
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/y8R29/3/)

Answer (score 0):

One, naive, approach (not taking objects, or nested arrays, into account):

```
function test() {
    var args = [];
    for (var i = 0, len = arguments.length; i < len; i++) {
        if (arguments[i] instanceof Array) {
            args = args.concat(arguments[i]);
        } else if (typeof arguments[i] === 'string') {
            args.push(arguments[i]);
        }
    }
    return (args);
}

var allPassedArguments = test([1, 2], 'something', ['more', 'array', 'goodness']);
console.log(allPassedArguments);
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/kkdWw/).

References:

- [`Array.prototype.concat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat).
- [`Array.prototype.push()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push).
- [`instanceof`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof).
- [`typeof`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof).

Comment: What would happen to arguments that are neither string nor array?

Comment: I haven't accounted for those, nor for multidimensional arrays; though I'd suspect that it's not terribly hard to do so.